# SmsManager crash on Samsung devices

Tags: android

I am receiving a crash log from Samsung devices when trying to send a multipart SMS message, this is the line which causes the crash:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendMultipartTextMessage(phone, null, SmsManager.getDefault().divideMessage(message), null, null)
```

Where `phone` is a fully specified non-nullable phone number and `message` is a long `String` (up to 300 characters) with ASCI symbols only. The only thing probably worth noting about it is maybe that it contains `\n\n` for text separation.

Here is the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()' on a null object reference
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1699)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1646)
com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendMultipartTextForSubscriber (ISms.java:1719)
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessageInternal (SmsManager.java:576)
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage (SmsManager.java:544)
```

I tried to look at the `SmsManager` source for the lines specified in the crash log, but to no avail - it seems that it has been modified by OEM.

This shouldn't be a permission issue either, since I check for SMS permission right before executing the `sendMultipartTextMessage` line.

The crash happened on Samsung Galaxy S6 and J530F phones. It has never been reported on anything other than those. And unfortunately I don't have a Samsung device to test this.

Has enyone encountered this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add more details and preferably write the full code of your current class

Comment: How are you sure that this part of code firstly throws exception? could you send complete stack trace, please?

Comment: You should put `SmsManager.getDefault().divideMessage(message)` out side of send arguments to find exception location better, IF it throws exception in first place. Even better you could test this function by putting it in some other place such as in `onCreate` of About Activity just for test purpose with some constant message value.

Comment: @BAHMAN You can see from the stack trace that it crashes at `android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage (SmsManager.java:544)` which is the method I'm referring to. As I mentioned, this crash happened only on Samsung devices and I wasn't able to reproduce it on my devices.

Comment: Genymotion emulator has some Samsung emulator images. can you test this code through this emulator? put these `divideMessage(message)` and `sendMultipartTextMessage` in two different lines in some test class to find problem better

Answer (score 0):

Special implementation for Samsung Galaxy S2 which has a nasty bug in the 4.0.3 update.

[See this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36942302)

```
private static class GalaxyS2IcsSmsManager extends DonutSmsManager {

    private static Method method;

    static {
        try {
            Class<?> classSmsManager = Class.forName("android.telephony.SmsManager");

            Class<?> paramTypes[] = new Class[9];

            paramTypes[0] = String.class;
            paramTypes[1] = String.class;
            paramTypes[2] = ArrayList.class;
            paramTypes[3] = ArrayList.class;
            paramTypes[4] = ArrayList.class;
            paramTypes[5] = Boolean.TYPE;
            paramTypes[6] = paramTypes[7] = paramTypes[8] = Integer.TYPE;

            method = classSmsManager.getMethod("sendMultipartTextMessage", paramTypes);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`Iterator` is usually to iterate a `List` and `sendMultipartTextMessage` has three parameters which are of `List` sub-type (specifically `ArrayList`).

Since a crash is happening, I would suggest to always ensure that these parameters are non-null. Hence instead of passing `null`, pass an empty `ArrayList` like so:

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = manager.divideMessage(message);
manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phone, null, parts != null ? parts : new ArrayList(),
    new ArrayList(), new ArrayList());
```

Note that I have not tried the solution and the last two parameter might need to stay `null` if this solution is causing a different error. Also this could cause an error elsewhere but hopefully not a crash. You could probably use a try-catch block where your current implementation is inside the try block and in the likelihood of an exception it would be caught and this solution's code would be executed or even handled differently (show an error message to the user). In such case that could minimize the error if implemented properly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the assumptions made are wrong. `SmsManager.divideMessage` would throw an exception if the message was null anyways and there is no need to pass `new ArrayList()` for sent and delivery pending intent parameters, not to say those are irrelevant at all.

Comment: As was mentioned, this crash happened only on Samsung devices. If there was something wrong with my implementation, it would crash on other devices too.

Comment: Yeah but what makes you sure that the output of `divideMessage` is not returning a `null` `ArrayList`? Also I mentioned that you might not need to pass `new ArrayList()` to the last two parameters which are sent and delivery pending intent parameters. I believe trying it out won't hurt and might solve the crash issue. Basically the exception is telling us that a certain list parameter is being processed however it is null and this cannot be misunderstood for something else.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, what I'm trying to say that there might be a weird behavior/implementation for `divideMessage` on Samsung devices only (so far). This solution is presented as a device compatibility work around to adjust the behavior in case it happens.